# How to determine what is different between 2 (identical) computers?

Tags: drivers, graphics, wine, amd-graphics

I have 2 old Gateway NE 522 computers. One had Windows 7, the other Windows 10. I loaded Ubuntu on both using the same boot from USB stick.

During set up, the former W7 machine could connect to internet and install extras during set up.  The W10 machine would not connect and therefore did not install extras.  After installation, however, I was able to get extras, just not during initial install.

As a graphics test, I installed Wine and World of Warcraft.

The former W7 machine, now Ubuntu 16.04 plays World of Warcraft between 40-80 fps. The former W10 machine, also Ubuntu 16.04 barely plays World of Warcraft at 3 fps.

On both machines, `lspci | grep VGA` outputs

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini [Radeon HD 8240 / R3 Series]
```

How can I get the former W10 machine up to the performance of the former W7 machine?

Comment: Assuming identical hardware, BIOS settings are a possible difference.

Comment: Please post the results of `cat /proc/cpuinfo`.

Comment: Patrick, results are 1763 characters too long. Shall I grep a specific bit for you?

Comment: @user1006177 You can put the output in a pastebin then [edit your quetion](http://askubuntu.com/posts/856212/edit) to add the link.